# What is the structuring convention of Interfaces in Java?

Tags: java, interface, conventions

Maybe seems to be unimportant, but how to structure an interface for readability if there are many methods? Is there any convention for that?

Do you group the methods by attributes (like example "interface a") or by type (getter, setter, everything else; like example "interface b") or in another way? What is best practice?

```java
public interface a {

 int getX();
 void setX(int x);

 int getY();
 void setY(int y);

 int getZ();
 void setZ(int z);

 int addTwo(int a, int b);
 float devideTwo(int a, int b);
 void update();
}
```

```java
public interface b {

 int getX();
 int getY();
 int getZ();

 void setX(int x);
 void setY(int y);
 void setZ(int z);

 int addTwo(int a, int b);
 float devideTwo(int a, int b);
 void update();
}
```

Comment: I tend to keep getter/setter pairs next to each other. In general, I like to keep related methods grouped together. Though in any case I don't put methods on consecutive lines (I keep one empty line between methods; besides, they'll have Javadoc comments). That said, this question has a decent chance of being closed as opinion-based.

Comment: "That said, this question has a decent chance of being closed as opinion-based." Since I see this question to be important, is stackoverflow just not the place for this kind of question, is there another section where it is allowed? where/how do I ask those kind of questions?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is opinion-based, so it doesn't really fit here on SO. However, there is not really a convention of how to order methods within an interface. I think it's more important to provide the methods with Javadoc, so the implementor can read the details of the methods to be implemented.

Comment: You could try other sites, such as Quora or Reddit. There may be [another Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) you could try, but I can't think of one at the moment that would accept a question like this.

Answer (score 0):

See, it's not about convention but about readability and convenience. As long as you're following the SOLID principles of OOPs you're good to go.

What I generally follow is the structure similar to that of **interface a**. This ensures that the getter and setter of a single variable are together which makes it convenient for another developer.